# Capture Image using Camera, File created but not returning in ActivityResult

Tags: android, file, android-intent, android-camera, onactivityresult

I have gone through most of the related question regarding the activityresult returning null using camera Intent. Here is my code below:

```
String filepath;
File file;
Bitmap bitmap;
int previewcount=0;
@OnClick(R.id.lnrcamera)
public void opencamera()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(this.getPackageManager()) != null)
    {
        try
        {
            file = createImageFile();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (file != null)
        {
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
            startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_CAMERA);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  // prefix
            ".jpg",         // suffix
            storageDir      // directory
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    filepath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

On ActivityResult

```
 else if (requestCode==FILE_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.d("sdfasdfasdf", "onActivityResult: "+filepath.isEmpty());
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(filepath));
            int newHeight = (bitmap.getHeight() * 500)/bitmap.getWidth();
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 500, newHeight, false);
            list_bitmap.add(bitmap);
            lnrpreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Adapter_Image adapter_expenseCategory=new Adapter_Image(this, 0, list_bitmap, new RecyclerCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPreviewDelete(List<Bitmap> list_bitmap)
                {
                    Log.d("hereornot", "onPreviewDelete: "+list_bitmap.size());
                    previewcount--;
                    if (list_bitmap.size()==0)
                    {
                        lnrpreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        imgpreviewcount.setImageResource(R.drawable.flagoff);
                    }
                    btxtpreviewcount.setBadgeCount(previewcount);
                }
            });
            recycler.setAdapter(adapter_expenseCategory);
            previewcount++;
            btxtpreviewcount.setBadgeCount(previewcount);
            imgpreviewcount.setImageResource(R.drawable.flagon);
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Activity_NewExpense.this, "Your device is out of Memory. Please free up some space.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            Log.d("hereornot", "onPreviewDelete: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.d("hereornot", "onPreviewDelete: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now the question is whenever I tried to open camera and get some photos the pictures are taken and it is in the memory too but the activity wont return me the file path. The testing device is running low on memory.However, for 1 or two clicks it works fine using camera, But more than two clicks it crashes and says this error :

> Unable to resume activity java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure
>   delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1,
>   data=null} to activity  java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2996)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3025)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3974)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:166)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)

Since the image might be big, I resized it and set the `largeheap=true` but unlucky me it didn't work. Could anyone guide me where I did wrong?

Comment: To avoid the oom errors try using an image loading library like Glide or Picasso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your process is being terminated when it is in the background. You need to hold onto your file location in the saved instance state `Bundle`, so you can get it back if needed.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.13/Camera/FileProvider) (from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android)) illustrates how to use the saved instance state `Bundle` to hold onto the file location. It also demonstrates how to use `FileProvider`, which you will need if you want your app to work on Android 7.0+ devices, as `Uri.fromFile()` [will not work](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).

Comment: Yup this is what has been happening entire time. But is there a way to prevent my activity from getting destroyed no matter what ?

Comment: No, you have no control over the system. If the camera app needs more memory to handle the picture capture, Android will kill any background app to free resources.

Comment: @JoshanTandukar: More importantly, this is not restricted to just launching the camera app. Any time that your app is no longer in the foreground, Android can terminate your process to free up RAM for use by other apps.

Comment: Got It Thanks.Thought I cannot do anything when this happens but I tried to recreate the bundle Instance Saving it before launching the Camera and retrieving back if the Exception Occurred. Thanks bro,It helped a lot. I had been stuck there for 5 days.

Answer (score 0):

If the user cancels the request, the data will be returned as NULL. The thread will throw a nullPointerException when you call `data.getExtras().get("data");`. I think you just need to add a conditional to check if the data returned is null.

Comment: Sorry Sir I for got to mention that data is always returning null but I am parsing from "filepath" but the image is already stored on the memory but yet "file.getAbsolutePath" is returning nothing . And cancel is working fine.